# Android and php live chat application

Tags: android, cakephp, livechat

we have to build a simple chat application on both android and cake php pointing to common database. I have searched on Internet  for basics to get started with chat application on Android. But I am not getting any good hints.
   Can u explain me how to start developing a server code for chat application on android?

Answer (score 0):

Some keywords to search for

- Websockets
- Long polling
- Comet

I'm pretty sure there are libs for Android available that will help with these techniques.